# JQuery Tools Tabs Behaving Erratically On Hover

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools

I am trying to use JQuery tabs to build a content area that will change when hovering over a tab to the right, and also auto rotate when not hovering over the content area or tabs. I have everything working for the most part as long as I don't quickly hover across multiple tabs. It seems to break and causes the auto rotate to start skipping through tabs erratically.

Here is what I am doing:

http://outreachi.com/marketing/2012/1212_tabtest/nav.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the demo](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover), they use `event: "mouseover"` instead of `hover`, have you given this a try?

Comment: I changed it, but it still seems still seems to be having a problem.

Comment: @user1356871 it seems to be the effect that is not finished when you go to the next pane, or the slideshow. Have you tried disabling them, just to make sure the basic tabs are working ok?

Comment: Yes I disabled the fade and it still is not working. It seems to be something in the slideshow plugin because when I take it off and just mouseover it works fine.

Comment: I was doing some research and it looks like a bug was introduced into jquery tools 1.2.6 that causes this problem. I am using 1.2.7. I switched back to 1.2.5 and it resolved the problem.